# Why doesn't module import while it actually exists?

Tags: python

My project structure looks like the following:

```
my-project:
   dialog
     utils
       path.py
```

After install by 'pip install .', in PyCharm, I can import successfully either of the two:

```
from dialog.utils import path
import dialog.utils
```

Then I can refer to it as below:

```
 path.module_path() // OR
 dialog.utils.module_path()
```

It doesn't run into any problem. I can also do this in iPython's terminal. However, when I run a python through terminal:

```
python3 run_dialog
```

run_dialog.py import 'path' as shown above, it always reports this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_dialog.py", line 15, in <module>
    import dialog.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dialog.utils'
```

So basically, I can run this code in both PyCharm and iPython terminal, but not in the project with 'python3 run_dialog'.

Why is that?

Comment: Do you have dunder modules, _ie_: `__init__.py` in your packages? There should be a dunder module in `dialog` and another in `utils`

Comment: Also when you run from the command line, prepend `PYTHONPATH=. python3 run_dialog` because as [@Yash Krishan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57596364/1020470) says, the interpreter will need to know where to look for modules when you say `import`. The default for this is your Python's `site-packages` folder. PyCharm and IPython add the current folder, `.` to the `PYTHONPATH` (aka `sys.path`) as a convenience.

Comment: if you are in a virtual environment, then in the command line, remember to activate the virtualenv by sourcing its `activate` script, _eg_: `path/to/myproj $ . venv/bin/activate` - the you should see the name of the virtualenv preceding the command line prompt, _eg_: `(venv) path/to/myproj $`

Comment: Yes. I have both __init__ in place. and also I activated the virtual environment. But still not working. Probably I have to set "PYTHONPATH" to project root directory first, in order to run any python script in a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/myModule/dir')
import myModule
```

The Python interpreter needs to know to path to your imported module.

However, a better approach would be setting PYTHONPATH to your project directory like this

```
set PYTHONPATH=my/path/to/project
```

Comment: But what' s the reason for that? It looks like standard python module structure.

Comment: It's in my virtual environment. I have a bunch of other imports starting with the prefix 'dialog' and it runs all fine without a problem. The only problem is with this 'dialog.utils'

Comment: It is because the terminal and IDE interpret the paths to your module differently

Comment: Exactly, because of the virtualenv, the paths and treated differently when running in IDE and terminal.

Comment: I meant 'dialog' is already installed as a module in my virtual environment.

Comment: Yes it is installed but when you run it from terminal as python3 run_dialog, the terminal doesn't know what happened inside the virtual environment and that is technically the purpose of having virtual environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198259/discussion-between-marlon-and-yash-krishan).

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the Pythonic solution would be to install your package in the activated virtual environment using an ["editable" install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs).

> “Editable” installs are fundamentally [“setuptools develop mode”](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) installs.

- use the [`pip install -e <path>` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-e) to do an [*editable* install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)

  ```
  (venv) $ pip install -e path/to/myproject  # wherever myproject/setup.py is located
  ```
- you can use `pip list` to confirm your package is installed into the virtualenv as an editable package, *ie* the path to the package is listed

  ```
  $ pip list
  myproject                0.1        path/to/myproject
  pip                      19.1.1
  setuptools               41.0.1
  ```
- changes saved to your package take effect each time you restart the interpreter and reload/import the package, letting you "edit" or "develop" your package